# Pronunciation of technical vocabulary

Tags: language

All knowledge of biology I have comes from online and after speaking for a brief period of time with someone from a biological education it is very clear that I have no knowledge of the pronunciation of all the necessary jargon I have learnt.

For example: Chordae Tendineae, Squamous Suture, Loop of Henle

How have people overcome this issue? I have searched online for pronunciation videos and whatnot, but very often they pronounce them differently to each other and it is impossible to know who is correct. I also do not want to learn the IPA for English.

Comment: "I also do not want to learn the IPA for English." - Yet this is clearly the best way to pronounce words where 1) you can find an IPA transcription for the word, and 2) you can't find a suitable audio source.

Comment: What's wrong with an online medical dictionary? E.g. [hĕn′lē](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/loop+of+Henle) (sounds like HEN-lee), or  [kor´dah] (pl. chor´dae) (L.) Pl. sounds like CORD-eye. I learned by hearing other people, so no other good suggestions. Eventually patterns emerge, esp. because of all the Latin.

Comment: Don't know if it'd work for you, but I handle it by basically doing all my technical communicating in writing.

Comment: Come on guys! Let's use some 21st century technology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to use the audio features of dictionaries on the internet.

Ideally you would buy a good scientific dictionary app with audio pronunciation for your iPhone, just as I have for foreign language dictionaries on mine. However, the scientific offerings I found on the app store did not fit the bill (there may be something hiding there that I missed), so I looked on the web, and what I found was:

[The Science Dictionary](https://www.thesciencedictionary.com)

Now this appears not to be an actual dictionary itself, but an aggregating site. So when I searched for *Chordae* I got several options, mainly from Wikipedia, which did *not* provide audio pronunciation, but also from

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chorda-tendinea)

which did — for both the singular (which is what is the listing) and the plural.

Dictionary.com doesn’t always provide audio pronunciations. When I tried *squamous suture* there was only a definition — but there were individual pronunciations for *squamous* and *suture*.

([Loop of Henle](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/loop-of-henle) was also there with pronunciation. Perhaps going directly to dictionary.com is your best bet.)

**Rider and caveat**

As @JM97 mentioned in a comment, some entries in [the free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com) have audio pronunciation, although others do not. There may be other on-line facilities that do likewise. However with any on-line dictionary one should ask oneself how reliable is the pronunciation; and it is difficult to tell because one doesn’t know how it is done in the way one does with a primary dictionary with a print reputation.

For example, take the pronunciation of the word "caeca". The [open dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Caeca) pronounces this in a classical Latin style with a hard C, whereas [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/caeca?s=t). pronounces it in a mediaeval Latin style with a soft C, the way it is pronounced by scientists I know who dissect it.

Comment: The free dictionary by farlex http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ is also very good.

Comment: @JM97 — I couldn't see any audio on the free dictionary.  Did I miss it somehow?

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/loop+of+henle see this example

Comment: Its a site which gives definitions from a large number of dictionaries including dorlands medical dictionary. just like science dictionary but the user does not have click an additional click.

Comment: @JM97 — Yes, I see there is an audio pronunciation for Loop of Henle, but not for Chordae Tendineae, which is why I had assumed it didn't support audio. (Also the app). I guess it varies. Another point is how reliable the pronunciations are. Compare the pronunciation of "caeca" on the open dictionary and dictionary.com. Better add a caveat to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth noting that in my experience, "accepted" pronunciation may vary quite a bit between biological disciplines and who a given specialist might have learned it from! For terms stolen directly from Latin, for example, there is often considerable variation between people about whether they should be pronounced in a Classical Latin style, an ecclesiastical/medieval Latin style, or (most commonly) an Anglicized style that sounds about right to an English-speaking biologist.

Names like the Loop of Henle are also tricky because they require you to know that they're anatomical structures named for particular people (in this case, [Friedrich Gustav Jakob Henle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Gustav_Jakob_Henle)), work out what language the person's last name is *from*, and then guess at what it is for an English speaker. English speakers do not always get this "right" on the first go, and weird pronunciations not infrequently result from confusions like this.

Personally, I wouldn't worry too much about it--I might just run pronunciations by a friend first and check to make sure I have them right there if I felt embarrassed.